# Gitlab self hosted - Unable to select an issue that is in the issue summary - "Unable to connect" error is displayed

Tags: gitlab-ce

Gitlab version "Community Edition v16.3.4" is running as a Docker container on my Synology NAS. I logged in as root, created a Group called Gitlab and then created an issue within the group. The issue is created correctly and is displayed in the issue summary page with a URL of:

[http://192.168.1.26:8888/dashboard/issues?sort=created_date&state=opened&assignee_username[]=root](http://192.168.1.26:8888/dashboard/issues?sort=created_date&state=opened&assignee_username%5B%5D=root)

When I select the issue from the list, the "Unable to connect - Firefox cannot establish a connection to the server at localhost" page is displayed.

The URL for this page is:

http://localhost/gitlab/configuration/-/issues/1

My external_url property is configured to be: 'http://localhost'.

It would seem to me that its URL is no longer being formatted correctly. I tried changing the external_url property to:

external_url "http://localhost:8888"

but this didn't seem to make any difference.

Can anyone suggest why I can create an issue but not view and edit it?

Thanks in advance.
Paul